# Export in object format via script. The default cube appears in the scene!

Tags: python, objects, export

I am importing a x3d file and then exporting in obj format using this simple script

```
import bpy,os

bpy.ops.import_scene.x3d(filepath='field.x3d', axis_forward='Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.x3d;*.wrl")

bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath='test.obj')
```

However the resulting obj file contains the default cube! This is the x3d file:

[image]

This is the object file after the export:
[image]

Why that cube appears ? Does someone know how to avoid the cube in the object file?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can't test so I wont answer.  Most import scene operators leave the newly imported objects as selected. Most exporters have a `use_selected` property. Hence can deselect all, import, export selected, [remove selected] in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the outliner in your first pic, the cube is there. Just delete the cube and it will no longer be exported.

Just because it isn't on a visible layer doesn't mean it wont be exported.